# Why can't QuantLib compile on its last release?

Tags: python-3.x, quantlib, quantlib-swig

After following the QuantLib 1.9 installation tutorial, I can't compile the library on my computer.

my setup
tutorial : https://www.quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml
python 3.6.3
Quantlib 1.9
Quantlib-SWIG 1.9
boost boost_1_66_0
visual studio 2017 
windows 10

My error is the following :

"running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'QuantLib._QuantLib' extension

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D__WIN32__ -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -DNOMINMAX (.....) IC:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\boost_1_66_0 /EHsc /TpQuantLib/quantlib_wrap.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\QuantLib/quantlib_wrap.obj /GR /FD /Zm250 /EHsc /bigobj /MD
quantlib_wrap.cpp
Info: Boost.Config is older than your compiler version - probably nothing bad will happen - but you may wish to look for an update Boost version.  Define BOOST_CONFIG_SUPPRESS_OUTDATED_MESSAGE to suppress this message.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO (....)/OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\QuantLib_QuantLib.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\QuantLib_QuantLib.cp36-win_amd64.lib /subsystem:windows /machine:x64

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: impossible d'ouvrir le fichier 'QuantLib-vc141-x64-mt.lib'

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104"

Wish someone could help with this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue installing QuantLib Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222547/issue-installing-quantlib-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It seems to be the same error. 
I downloaded VS 2015 but I am not sure that it can handle the two version (2015 and 2017) of VS on the same machine.
I have been suggested to find a wheel for QuantLib 1.16 on internet and it worked.